# winapi: make modeless dialog ignore accelerators

Tags: c, winapi

My main application has accelerators that are numeric keys. When I had a modal dialog (`DialogBox()`) with a text field, those keys could be used to type the value in the text field. But when I made it modeless (`CreateDialog()`), numeric keystrokes stopped going to the text field, even though it's selected. Non-accelerator keys go there as needed, as well as numpad numbers. All the rest just get fed to the main application, that executes them as hotkeys.

So I need the main app to ignore accelerators whenever the focus is on the dialog text field. Am I missing some dialog parameter, or it has to do with main app hotkey handling?

Comment: Offhand, is there an [`IsDialogMessage()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms645498(v=vs.85).aspx) in your main message pump? If not, put one there and ensure if it returns TRUE you do *not* pass the message through your accelerators and/or dispatcher. The standard model (in pseudo) `while getmsg { if !isdialogmessage { translate; dispatch} }`

Comment: That looks very sane, but can something be done about a dialog that doesn't have a global HWND (required for isdialogmessage)? I just call the function directly instead of `DialogHWnd=CreateDialog()`.

Comment: You need the window handle of the dialog box to be accessible to do this. which I would have expected you retained regardless since sending the dialog messages (like any other window) requires it. It sounds like you need to add either a global or an extern (you could have the creation function grow up a sub loop that does what I described until the dialog box is closed, but that gets rather hairy to manage).